# Arranging numbers in order for increasing

Tags: java

I am writing a program that arranges the elements in the array with the max being at the very end then would decrease in size as they move backwards in an array. I could just arrange them with smallest being first and so forth but I want to see if I could do the other way around. Below is my code.It does not work beyond the first iteration. Could anyone help me.

```
import java.util.Scanner;//Importing scanner class.
import java.util.Arrays;//Importing the array class.

{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
         double [] numbers= {5,3,6,4,1};
         double currentMax;
         int currentMaxIndex;
         int i,j,k;

       //  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);//Creating a scanner.

         //The below lines are used to ask the user to enter 10 numbers.

        /* for (k = 0;k<numbers.length;k++)
         {
             System.out.print("Enter number " + k +" : ");
             numbers[k]=input.nextDouble();
         }//end of for loop.
         */
         for(i=numbers.length-1;i>1;i--)
         {
             currentMax=numbers[i];
             currentMaxIndex=i;

             for(j=numbers.length-2;j>0;j--)
             {
                 if(currentMax<numbers[j])
                 {currentMax=numbers[j];
                 currentMaxIndex=j;
                 }
             }
             if(currentMaxIndex!=i)
             {
                 numbers[currentMaxIndex]=numbers[i];
                 numbers[i]=currentMax;
             }
         }
    System.out.print("The sorted new array is:\n");
    for(i=0;i<numbers.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.print(numbers[i]+" ");
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you're looking for is a simple insertion sort.

Answer (score 1):

Although it doesn't directly answer your question, it does offer a reasonable alternative approach.

Refactor your code as follows:

Step 1: Delete all your code

Step 2: Type this instead:

```
Arrays.sort(numbers);
```

Comment: `Arrays.sort(numbers, Collections.reverseOrder());` if he wants decreasing order (I couldn't tell from his question). If you want to use this method you need to change to `Double[] numbers = new Double[]{5., 3., 6., 4., 1.};` as well.

Comment: I need to arrange starting from the end being the max and then the previous being second biggest and so forth.

Comment: @atomman he wants it lowest to highest (he's trying to *process* it last to first, but Arrays.sort() will do what he wants)

Comment: Array sort will work but I need to do this as part of my assignment. I want to work on it but I am just stuck somewhere. I am not one of those like to copy results from the web. I want to understand it first.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously there are better ways to sort, but I think this should fix your code:

The outer loop should be checking for `i >= 1` and the inner loop for `j >= 0`.